# Combine tensorflow low level API (tensors/placeholders) with Keras model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

According to [tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras#build_advanced_models). Using `tf.keras.Input` gives a placeholder and using `tf.keras.layers.Dense` gives a Tensor. So I wanted to test the equivalence using Tensors and Placeholders with tensorflow low level API's and then use the keras high level API to train my model. This is my code:

```
tf.reset_default_graph()  

inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 32])
W_h = tf.get_variable(name="W_h", shape=[32, 64], initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.01))
W_out = tf.get_variable(name="W_out", shape=[64, 10], initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.01))

h = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(inputs, W_h, name="MatMul"), name='relu')
predictions = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h, W_out, name="MatMul"), name='relu')

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=predictions)
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='sgd') # sgd stands for stochastic gradient descent
model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=5)
```

However, upon call to `tf.keras.Model` I get the error:

```
InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype float and shape [?,32]
     [[{{node Placeholder}}]]
```

I do give the input a placeholder right?

---

PS: full error message:

```
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-27f92d1f784d> in <module>
      8 predictions = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h, W_out, name="MatMul"), name='relu')
      9 
---> 10 model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=predictions)
     11 model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='sgd') # sgd stands for stochastic gradient descent
     12 model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=5)

~\.conda\envs\tensorflow_cpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    127 
    128   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
--> 129     super(Model, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    130     # initializing _distribution_strategy here since it is possible to call
    131     # predict on a model without compiling it.

~\.conda\envs\tensorflow_cpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\network.py in __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    160         'inputs' in kwargs and 'outputs' in kwargs):
    161       # Graph network
--> 162       self._init_graph_network(*args, **kwargs)
    163     else:
    164       # Subclassed network

~\.conda\envs\tensorflow_cpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\tracking\base.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    455     self._self_setattr_tracking = False  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    456     try:
--> 457       result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    458     finally:
    459       self._self_setattr_tracking = previous_value  # pylint: disable=protected-access

~\.conda\envs\tensorflow_cpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\network.py in _init_graph_network(self, inputs, outputs, name, **kwargs)
    267 
    268     if any(not hasattr(tensor, '_keras_history') for tensor in self.outputs):
--> 269       base_layer_utils.create_keras_history(self._nested_outputs)
    270 
    271     self._base_init(name=name, **kwargs)

~\.conda\envs\tensorflow_cpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer_utils.py in create_keras_history(tensors)
    198     keras_tensors: The Tensors found that came from a Keras Layer.
    199   """
--> 200   _, created_layers = _create_keras_history_helper(tensors, set(), [])
    201   return created_layers
    202 

~\.conda\envs\tensorflow_cpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer_utils.py in _create_keras_history_helper(tensors, processed_ops, created_layers)
    242             constants[i] = op_input
    243           else:
--> 244             constants[i] = backend.function([], op_input)([])
    245       processed_ops, created_layers = _create_keras_history_helper(
    246           layer_inputs, processed_ops, created_layers)

~\.conda\envs\tensorflow_cpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\backend.py in __call__(self, inputs)
   3290 
   3291     fetched = self._callable_fn(*array_vals,
-> 3292                                 run_metadata=self.run_metadata)
   3293     self._call_fetch_callbacks(fetched[-len(self._fetches):])
   3294     output_structure = nest.pack_sequence_as(

~\.conda\envs\tensorflow_cpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1456         ret = tf_session.TF_SessionRunCallable(self._session._session,
   1457                                                self._handle, args,
-> 1458                                                run_metadata_ptr)
   1459         if run_metadata:
   1460           proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype float and shape [?,32]
     [[{{node Placeholder}}]]
```

Comment: Which TF version are you running?

Comment: `print(tf.version.VERSION)` gives 1.14.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't mix `tf.placeholder` and `tf.keras.Input`. In other words, if you want to use the `tf.keras` API then use `tf.keras.Input`, or if you want to use the `tf` native API the go with `tf.placeholder`. In addition, your choice will reflect other parts of your code. Assuming that you want to go with the `tf.keras` API, the approach you should partake is the following:

```
class CustomLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):

    def __init__(self, output_dim, **kwargs):
        self.output_dim = output_dim
        super(CustomLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        # Create a trainable weight variable for this layer.
        self.kernel = self.add_weight(name='kernel', 
                                      shape=tf.TensorShape((input_shape[1], self.output_dim)),
                                      initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.01),
                                      trainable=True)
        super(CustomLayer, self).build(input_shape)  # Be sure to call this at the end

    def call(self, x):
        return tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(x, self.kernel))

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return (input_shape[0], self.output_dim)

inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(32,), dtype=tf.float32)
h = CustomLayer(output_dim=64)(inputs)
predictions = CustomLayer(output_dim=10)(h)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=predictions)
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='sgd') # sgd stands for stochastic gradient descent
model.summary()
model.fit(np.random.rand(100,32), np.random.rand(100,10), batch_size=32, epochs=5)
```

Please note that this approach is relevant if we consider that you use TF 1.14 as you mentioned in the comments. On TF 2.0, this is less complicated and more intuitive. On the other hand, if you want to stick to the TF 1.14 native API, and use `tf.placeholder`, then you should build the graph using `tf.placeholder` as nodes that you will use to feed the data. Moreover, regarding your question whether `tf.keras.Input` returns a placeholder - It does return a placeholder node, that you can use to feed your data. But it does not return a `tf.placeholder`. The usage of `tf.placeholder` is the following:

```
X = tf.placeholder(shape=None, dtype=tf.int32)
Y = tf.placeholder(shape=None, dtype=tf.int32)
add = X + Y
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(add, feed_dict={X: 2, Y: 3}))
    # 5
    print(sess.run(add, feed_dict={X: 10, Y: 9}))
    # 19
```

As you can see, a static graph is created, and then its nodes are executed with a `tf.Session` while feeding data in the graph using the `tf.placeholder`. On the other hand, `tf.keras.Input` serves the same purpose (That is why in the documentation is called a placeholder), but its use case is relevant with the `tf.keras` API and not with the `tf` native API.

Comment: I do agree it's weird and I can't think of right now an example when this will be necessary. However, I am trying to understand, if `tf.keras.Input` gives back a placeholder, why wouldn't it work that way?

On another topic, that code doesn't work for me, it ask me to initialize variables (W_h and W_out)

Comment: I mean, the error tells me to do exactly what I am doing. This is more a "knowledge" type question than a practical work. I'm more into theory that finding the code that works.

Comment: I tried to summarize the differences between `tf` and `tf.keras`. Please see my updated answer as well as the updated code. Also, let me know if you need any extra information.

Comment: Thank you for the information. It is very useful. however, I fail to correctly understand the phrase " It does return a placeholder node, that you can use to feed your data. But it does not return a `tf.placeholder`" what would be the exact difference?

Comment: Updated again. Let me know.